# how to build multiple flutter apps, firebase as the common backend for all?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have been trying to create multiple apps using a single firebase as the backend.is there any way to connect them?

I have developed a food delivery app using flutter and firebase. but now I need an admin app for the same firebase to access full privilege to handle the firebase but the integration on firebase is not possible to connect different named flutter app.

if anyone knows the method to implement this plz explain

thank u...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add more than one App to your firebase console

Click the add app option and further procedure is the same as you have done for the previous app

[image]